# Getting through local proxy when connecting to a SOAP service in Java

Tags: c#, java, soap, proxy, wsdl

So I have used wsimport to create the required Java files from a given WSDL to connect to a remote web service (asmx) and can successfully connect from a non-proxy environment

The web service was written is C# and I have managed to connect to it by creating a C# test program.

However I need to get through my local proxy in Java, which I achieved in C# by setting the `client.ChannelFactory.Windows.ClientCredentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials` (where client is an instance of my web service).

Can anyone tell me what the equivalent is in Java as I can't find anywhere to set them.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

System properties:

http.proxyHost
http.proxyPort
https.proxyHost
https.proxyPort